# div, that expands on focus, with nested input element. How to make div expansion persist on input focus?

Tags: javascript

I have a div with a `tabindex` attribute that lets it receive focus, and when it does so, it is expanded (to display a few different options) through a JS event listener assigning it the class `focus`. Now, nested within the div is a text input (used to let the user specify a custom value instead of the default options), and when that receives focus, the div triggers a blur event, but I don't want the div to be shrunken when this happens.

How would you go about solving this?

*Ideally, the blur event for the input element would also determine if the div is the new active element and in that case not shrink the div.*

Comment: without seeing any example code you might be able to use `reventDefault()` to prevent that

Comment: `preventDefault()` doesn't work, neither does `stopPropagation()`. But a problem seems to be that no matter how I adjust bubbling, the blur event on the div always fires before the focus event on the input does. That way I can't get the `document.activeElement` in the div's blur event listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is a bit hackish, but it should provide a working solution to anyone else who encounters this issue.

`.color-picker` (which is the div to be expanded) has a `tabindex` attribute that allows it to be focused, and `onfocus` it calls  a function that adds the class *focus* to the element in question. Furhtermore, the function also creates an empty div with the class `close-color-picker-overlay`. That div has:

- A `position: fixed` with `bottom`, `left`, `right` & `top` styles all set to 0, making the div cover all of the page.
- A `z-index` style 1 less than `.color-picker.focus`'s
- A `tabindex` attribute 1 more than `.color-picker`.

This means that as soon as the user clicks outside of the `.color-picker` or focuses on something else (eg. by clicking tab), `.close-color-picker-overlay` receives focus. For that very event, there's an event listener that runs a `querySelector` for `.color-picker.focus` and removes the class *focus* from the element it finds. Then it removes `.close-color-picker-overlay` from the DOM, resetting everything to the original state.

This way, focusing the input element nested within `.color-picker`, doesn't interfere with anything.

I also made [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leopld/RZ3Rg/) to more clearly illustrate how I went about hacking this problem (should anyone ever encounter a similar one).

Comment: I'll mark this answer as accepted, because the issue is solved through this approach. But if anyone has a more standards solution, I'd love to hear it :)

Comment: It turns out [GitHub](https://github.com) does something very similar with their *context menus* (eg. menus that let one filter issues by milestones). The biggest difference is that they only listen for clicks to the overlay div.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem while creating a focusable context menu. The main issue is that the next element has not yet been focussed when focusout/blur fires, so it's impossible to determine whether it is a child of the blurred element. I figured I could just delay the focus out function until it had been:

```
$('.something').on('blur', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (that.has(document.activeElement).length)) {
            return;
        }
        // Some close logic.
        that.hide();
    }, 0),
});
```

The `setTimeout(fn, 0)` schedules execution of the close logic after any currently pending code (which in this case includes focusing the other element). Seems to work for me in FF 18.0 at least; currently don't have any browsers here but I'm thinking it might work in others as well.